# Calculating B+ tree memory usage (minimum, maximum)

Tags: database, indexing, b-tree, b-plus-tree

I have a B+ tree index containing 10M leaves. I know that a block size in the memory is 4KB, and that RAM is also 4KB.
How can I calculate what is the maximum and minimum memory usage?

also, how can I tell what is the actual storage space allocated to the index?

thanks

Comment: Have you considered your own solution first? If so, what does it look like and why do you think it might be right or wrong?

Comment: I couldn't solve it. I don't know that much about calculating storage usage. Thats why Im having trouble solving it

Comment: You might want to break the question down into smaller parts, like how to calculate storage usage in general, starting with a few very specific cases. Once you understand the concepts, then the original b+tree question becomes easier to solve.